# modifications dont display on gerrit webUI

Tags: gerrit

after I push the modifications to gerrit,the reviewer want to review the modifications, but the modifications dont highlight,it seems like there is no modifications in the file

Comment: Have you executed "git add / commit" / push" locally?

Comment: yes,already executed git add/commit/push, it's strange, other files can highlight the modifications in the same commit, only one file cannt highlight.

Comment: Please add more information about the issue, like screenshots and used commands.

Comment: there are 4 files modified in local, after finished the modification, run the command: git add . /git commit/git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master, when review the modifications on gerrit ui, only one file dont highlight the modifications, others dont have. I dont know why I cannt paste the screenshot